# How to set input field to empty which is used as autocomplete in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am an input field that I am using for autocomplete so after selecting an option I want to clear that input field that is used as a autocomplete. bellow is my example but it's not working.
`$('#autocomplete').val('')` is doing nothing.

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: my_url,
    select: function ( event, ui){
        $('#autocomplete').val('')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer to ensure the code inside run at the end.

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
      source: my_url,
      select: function ( event, ui){
         setTimeout(() => {
              $('#autocomplete').val("");
            }, 1);
      }
   }
)
```